# Mysql bad performance

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-performance

I have this simple table

```
CREATE TABLE `user_did_something` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `something_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Indexes for table `user_did something`
ALTER TABLE `user_did_something`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

and when I try to insert with

```
INSERT INTO user_did_something (something_id, user_id) VALUES (1,11)
```

the time for execution is ~70ms.

Testhing the same structure on different machine, the execution time is ~3ms.

Additional information:

- version `10.0.28-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04`
- table has no rows
- only index is for the column `id` which is primary.

I have no idea how to debug this. Read some stuff online, restarted everything, still same result.

I am looking for a guidance on how to debug stuff like this without the need of reinstalling the mysql server on my machine.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` does not say that you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`; please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` again.

Comment: What other queries might have been touching the same table at the same time?  Was the 70ms immediately after restarting the server, in which case the table was not yet opened, plus other not-yet-cached things.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the question. The server is for testing and nothing is touching the table while I executed the queries. Have tested it after 2 days of running without restart, have tested it after restart also. Every time the query takes around 70-120 ms. Most times it takes around 70ms

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not make it the `PRIMARY KEY`.  You have no indexes on the table.

Comment: Follow my tips on [_many:many mapping tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table), which include getting rid of `id`.

Comment: _"different machine"_ - are the hardware specs on these different machines exactly the same?  Are you executing these via the terminal on both?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the hardware on the "different machine" has lower specs. And still the query is faster.

Comment: Is there a performance difference on other queries with these two machines, or is it only this query and/or this table where there's a difference?

Comment: @RickJames Edited the question from the dump. Even without indexes the query should be faster

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Every query is slower.

Comment: Have you compared the configurations of the two databases?  See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqld-configuration-files-and-groups/

Comment: @MikeNakis same configurations

Comment: 70ms is about 7 disk hits in an old spinning drive.  No amount of config or hardware differences are likely to explain it.  If `CREATE TABLE` were involved, then I could understand it; I can't explain it for inserting one row into an existing table.

Comment: @RickJames Everything is set up. (there is no create table) Only the insert query is executed.

Comment: Strange.  Consider filing a bug report with mariadb.com.

Comment: There are way too many variables of hardware, os, load, server state, warm up, replication, network latency, network topology, etc for this question to be useful. Narrow things down with repeatable precise definitions of everything that could affect performance (which is a lot of things).

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a guidance on how to debug stuff like this without the need of reinstalling the mysql server on my machine.

I'll try to answer this part of your question. So you'd like to peek under-the-hood of some process, and see what it's doing. You don't want to recompile it, reinstall it or relaunch it, and you don't want to be limited by the tracing that it ships with out-of-the-box.

This is a good opportunity to use [DTrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/)! It lets you watch what your processes are doing (and [much](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) [more](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/06/30/tweaking-memory-on-the-fly/)).

DTrace is available on at least Solaris, Mac OS X* and FreeBSD, and [I hear a port exists for Linux](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux). Otherwise you could trace similar information using a different utility ([BPF tracing got merged into Linux 4.9-rc1 recently](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-10-27/dtrace-for-linux-2016.html)).

**Mac OS X users will need to [explicitly permit DTrace to run](http://internals.exposed/blog/dtrace-vs-sip.html), by excluding it from System Integrity Protection*

You can watch `mysqld` in real-time as it enters and returns from functions:

```bash
dtrace -p $(pgrep -x mysqld) -F -n 'pid$target:mysqld::entry{} pid$target:mysqld::return{}'
```

As an example of some output… InnoDB is quite chatty even when idle:

```
2  -> sync_arr_wake_threads_if_sema_free    
6  -> os_event_reset                        
2    -> os_mutex_enter                      
6  <- os_event_reset                        
2    <- os_mutex_enter                      
6  -> pfs_mutex_exit_func                   
6  <- pfs_mutex_exit_func                   
2    -> os_mutex_exit                       
6  -> os_event_reset                        
2    <- os_mutex_exit                       
6  <- os_event_reset
```

You can watch queries entering the MySQL dispatcher!

```bash
dtrace -p $(pgrep -x mysqld) -F -n 'pid$target:mysqld:*dispatch_command*:entry{printf("Query: %s\n", copyinstr(arg2));}'
```

Sample output:

```
CPU FUNCTION                                 
0  -> dispatch_command(enum_server_command, THD*, char*, unsigned int) Query: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'pid_file'
```

I believe it's also within the capabilities of DTrace to listen for function calls that happen *whilst a particular query runs*. For example: you could make `mysqld:*dispatch_command*:entry` init a thread-local variable iff the query matches some criteria, and make `pid$target:mysqld::entry|return` print only whilst that variable is defined. The corresponding `mysqld:*dispatch_command*:exit` or similar could then undefine that variable. You could alternatively use global variables of course if you are expecting the work to occur in a separate thread.

*Sorry for not writing a concrete example of the above; my own MySQL is hosed, and my DTrace book is at the office.*

Brendan Gregg, author of the [DTraceToolkit](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtracetoolkit.html) provides many sample scripts that may be useful for monitoring your errant process, including [some one-liners](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit) for watching whether the process is encountering page faults, how big are its read and writes, what syscalls it's making, etc. But you can do far better than one-liners if you learn DTrace more fully.

---

The scripts I presented here are based on the ones presented in Ben Rockwood's article, [Examining MySQL in real time using DTrace](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/tip/Examining-MySQL-in-real-time-using-DTrace). Requires free registration to read.

I learned about this tool from Brendan Gregg's articles, and learned more about DTrace from Brendan's [DTrace book](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/02/23/dtrace-book-sample-chapter-file-systems/). I highly recommend this book, if you would like to see how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and solved the problem by restarting MySQL. but as you said, you tried that before. I recommend to:

Check Firewall, if you have on your Ubuntu.

Check cache size and check if it is ON:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE have_query_cache;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE query_cache_size;
```

Check What process running and maybe slowing down:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Check which query cost you more by x$statement_analysis:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.`x$statement_analysis`
```

Check global status. You can find very useful information there, like `Threads_connected`:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
```